# I need to reference kendo grid in angularjs controller written in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, controller

In the html template I have

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.myGrid" k-options="vm.defaultGridOptions" />
```

In the related component class (implements ng.IComponentOptions) I specify the

```
this.controllerAs = 'vm';
```

And in the controller code

```
class MyController{
    ...
    static $inject = ['$log', '$scope']
    constructor(protected $log: ng.ILogService,
        protected $scope: ng.IScope){

        this.defaultDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(<kendo.data.DataSourceOptions>{ ...}

        this.defaultGridOptions = {
            dataSource: this.defaultDataSource,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: 'someField',
                    title: 'Some field',
                    width: 50
                },
                {
                    command: [{
                            template: '<span class="k-button" ng-click="vm.onSomeEvent($event)"> Click Here</span>'
                        }],
                    width: 60
                }

    }
```

and in the onSomeEvent method I want to retrieve the selected item, using something like this

```
    private onSomeEvent($event): void{
        var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");//well, I tried some other approaches too
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        //use the selectedItem
    }
```

Which does not work, because the 'grid' is undefined. This raises two questions:

- How to properly reference the myGrid?
- Is there a better way to get the selected item, considering that I have access to both defaultGridOptions and defaultDataSource?

Maybe a trivial question, but I am new to angular/typescript/kendo and I have spent already some non-trivial time on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that the good solution is to add a kendoGrid property into the controller:

```
private myGrid: kendo.ui.Grid;
```

and later use it in the handler as a normal property

```
private onSomeEvent($event): void{

    var selectedItem = this.myGrid.dataItem($($event.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    //use the selectedItem
}
```